# Primeng angular 7 - css is not getting applied

Tags: css, angular, input, primeng

I am using angular 7 and primeng library for UI compnents. CSS is not getting applied to the HTML elements. I have imported these css files in `angular.json`:

```
           "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
```

On the demo page: http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputgroup

Input box have these classes generated: `ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget`

These are missing from my generated html, if i apply these classes manually css gets applied. This is HTML code:

```
<h3 class="first">Addons</h3>
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon"><i class="pi pi-user" style="line-height: 1.25;"></i></span>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Username">         
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Price">   
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">.00</span>      
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">www</span>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Website">      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `ViewEncapsulation`:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ..
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

There is no change in `app.module.ts` for primeng.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Per My Example You need to change in app.module.ts file

See below Images

You need to import **InputTextModule** from primeng in root module of your component
[image]

And here is the angular.json file

[image]

Comment: This has worked, i didnt find importing it in there docs. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you find this helpfull...

I had the same problem, then I tried to put the css files into my styles.css instead of angular.json and it works fine now

change this...(angular.json)

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
```

by this...(src/styles.scss):

```
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css';
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install primeng-lts

Add to below styles to **angular.json**

```
  "styles": [
          "./node_modules/primeng-lts/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng-lts/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
        ],
```